# Socket connection lost and foreground service is kill by OS after some time

Tags: android, socket.io, foreground-service

I have an chat app with socket.IO and make a connection to the server. I don't know witch services and processes are turn off on stand by and when phone is not charging or maybe when is use a lot of memory.
When I test the app on emulator everything is working fine but on real device sometimes app disconnect, or sometimes kill the service.

I try with wakelock and wifilock in onCreate method in service and connection disconnect usually after 20minutes. It is like I added few more minutes but again the connection is lost.

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Hi-tech::PowerWakeLock");
        wl.acquire(10000);
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF , "MyWifiLock");
        wifiLock.acquire();
```

Answer (score 0):

Which sdk version are you targeting? If you're targeting >25 then this indicates that wake locks will not be useful in your case.

> As one of the changes that Android 8.0 (API level 26) introduces to improve battery life, when your app enters the cached state, with no active components, the system releases any wakelocks that the app holds.

Further explanation of cached state:

> Services that have been running for a long time (such as 30 minutes or more) may be demoted in importance to allow their process to drop to the cached LRU list described next. This helps avoid situations where very long running services with memory leaks or other problems consume so much RAM that they prevent the system from making effective use of cached processes.

This is not a solution to your problem but it might be an explanation.

Comment: Yes, I targeting >25 sdk version. What do you recommend? I need a stable service and connection, for much more long time than 30 minutes. It' not problem if it drain battery, I just need the service to be not killed and stable connection. I try to make app to not be optimized in battery options but it didn't help